# C# Tcp is losing packets?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, chat

I wrote a C# chat software that uses a new (at least for me) system that I called request system. I don't know if that has been created before, but for now I think of it as my creation :P

Anyhow, this system works like this:

1. soc receives a signal
2. checks the signal
3. if the data it just received is the number 2, the client software knows that the server is about to send a chat message. if the number is 3, so the client knows that the server is about to send the member list, and so on.

The problem is this: when I do step-by-step in VS2012 it works fine, the chat is working properly. When I use it on debug mode or just run it on my desktop, there seems to be missing data, and it shouldn't be because the code is working just fine...

Example of code for the sending&receiving message on client:

```
    public void RecieveSystem()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] req = new byte[1];
            soc.Receive(req);
            int requestID = int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req));
            if (requestID == 3)
            {
                byte[] textSize = new byte[5];
                soc.Receive(textSize);
                byte[] text = new byte[int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(textSize))];
                soc.Receive(text);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { ChatBox.Text += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(text) + "\r\n"; });
            }
        }
    }

    public void OutSystem(string inputText)
    {
        byte[] req = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("3");
        soc.Send(req);
        byte[] textSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(inputText).ToString());
        soc.Send(textSize);
        byte[] text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);
        soc.Send(text);
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }
```

and on the server:

```
    public void UpdateChat(string text)
    {
        byte[] req = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("3");
        foreach (User user in onlineUsers)
            user.UserSocket.Send(req);
        byte[] textSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text).ToString());
        foreach (User user in onlineUsers)
            user.UserSocket.Send(textSize);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        foreach (User user in onlineUsers)
            user.UserSocket.Send(data);
    }
           public void RequestSystem(Socket soc)
        {
~~~
                    }
                    else if (request == 3)
                    {
                        byte[] dataSize = new byte[5];
                        soc.Receive(dataSize);
                        byte[] data = new byte[int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataSize))];
                        soc.Receive(data);
                        UpdateChat(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (!soc.Connected)
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { OnlineMembers.Items.Remove(decodedName + " - " + soc.RemoteEndPoint); Status.Text += soc.RemoteEndPoint + " Has disconnected"; });
                        onlineUsers.Remove(user);
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is that "~~~" part in server code sample? Is that an unimportant code or you missed something?

Comment: You may be interested in my article [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/A_11178-A-Peer-To-Peer-LAN-Chat-Application-in-Visual-Basic-Net-using-TcpClient-and-TcpListener.html), especially the section entitled "Stream Of Consciousness - He's Talking A Lot, But Not Really Making Any Sense!"

Comment: TCP isn't inside C#, and TCP doesn't lose packets.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan it is an unimportant code :) 
EJP I know, I never said it's in C#... and I know it doesn't lose packets, that's why I got confused and thought that something is wrong.

My code is working now, but I have another problem. I'll be glad if you could help me there :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022162/socket-doesnt-work-on-external-ip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assuming that you'll have one packet for each `Send` call. That's not stream-oriented - that's packet-oriented. You're sending multiple pieces of data which I suspect are coalesced into a single packet, and then you'll get them all in a single `Receive` call. (Even if there are multiple packets involved, a single `Receive` call could still receive all the data.)

If you're using TCP/IP, you should be thinking in a more stream-oriented fashion. I'd also encourage you to change the design of your protocol, which is odd to say the least. It's fine to use a length prefix before each message, but why would you want to encode it as text when you've got a perfectly good binary connection between the two computers?

I suggest you look at `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`: use `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` rather than `Socket` (or at least use `NetworkStream`), and use the reader/writer pair to make it easier to read and write pieces of data (either payloads or primitives such as the length of messages). (`BinaryWriter.Write(string)` even performs the length-prefixing for you, which makes things a lot easier.)

Comment: Man you are fast! ty for your answer, umm so can I change my protocol\socket type or something to be packet-oriented? How does stream works?

Comment: @user3348638: Well you could use UDP instead, but that opens up a whole other can of worms. See my final paragraph for a more stream-oriented approach.

Comment: @user3348638 UDP is packet-orianted, but don't be tempted by it's seemingly simpler mechanics; having to deal with duplicate/unordered/missing packets isn't fun. Not that TCP guarantees this, but makes it rare enough to assume for most applications.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: I thought TCP actually *did* guarantee ordering, no duplication and no missing packets. I thought that was the point... (Obviously packets can *go* missing, but they're resent automatically and you don't need to worry. If the connection is dropped entirely, you should get an error rather than just continuing with bad data.)

Comment: Wait, isn't the TCP does guarantee that ALL the data I send will be recieved in the right order? I'm very confused right now. Is TCP even good for chat? and the stream you talked about, if I understand it correctly, It creates a stream between the client and server, and you need to write to it via Stream class in System.IO or BinaryWriter (Which I don't really know about). I don't think I want a stream, but something else, I don't know how to call it - just send a single data piece to the client every time and close or something. SIMPLE would be the best. Is there anything like it?

Comment: @user3348638: Yes, TCP guarantees that all the data will be received once, and in the right order. It's fine for chat, and I'd advise you to stick with it. As Mr. Smith said, you don't want the headaches of deduplication etc yourself. UDP is *also* fine for chat, but comes with more headaches - and as it sounds like you're *relatively* new to network programming, I'd stick with TCP/IP for the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet You got me, I am new :P
First, thank you for the help guys, I really appreciate it. 
Second, so basicly if I replace the socket with a TCP Client and creates a stream, and then writing over it with BinaryWriter it would solve my missing data problem?

Comment: @user3348638: Well you should rethink your whole protocol, but yes - changing to be stream-oriented will work. Note that you're already using a stream-oriented protocol, it's just you're *trying* to use it as if it were packet-oriented (or at least message-oriented).

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I'll try the BinaryWriter. Thank you for your help. :)